# Restrição de palavras

Tags: html, css

Fala, pessoal.

Eu gostaria de saber como restringir certas palavras, tipo, uma pessoa tenta escrever 'PQP', então o site não deixa esta palavra ficar lá.

**HTML5 - CSS - JS**

Comment: Guarda uma blacklist de palavras que não deseja aceitar em uma array com javascript, ai só verifica a palavra quando o usuário faz alguma ação.

Comment: Você vai precisar de uma linguagem de programação, fazer uma lista das palavras que não quer, e utilizar funções para bloquear essas palavras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom apesar que você pode fazer no HTML também.

```html
<form action="">
  Palavra : <input type="text" name="palavra" pattern="^((?!PQP).)*$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Dessa forma a string "PQP" não é permitida.
Se a resposta estiver correta, poderia validá-la.

Para montar as expressões para várias palavras você precisará do operador "ou"("|").

[Aqui pode ver como fazer as expressões](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/metacaracteres.html)

Comment: Quando aparece aquela mensagem falando "É preciso que o formato corresponda ao exigido", eu posso alterar o texto da mensagem?? Se sim, como?

Comment: E como eu posso adicionar mais palavras na tag PATTERN?

Comment: Para alterar a mensagem vc pode usar o atributo oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Sua mensagem ')"...Para adicionar mais palavras na expressão regular, vocÊ vai precisar usar o operador"|" "ou", recomendo ler o link sobre expressões que deixei...abraço